# How can we use saml in postman

Tags: web-services, testing, postman, saml

I have created a spring boot project and implemented saml in it. I have used okta as an IDP. I want to test the services of my project using postman. How can we use saml in postman.

Answer (score 1):

Postman is for OAuth2 REST API.

This concept does not exist in SAML so you can't use Postman.

You could use the SAML IDP Initiated flow via Okta or the SP Initiated flow from your application.

To see what's happening, use [SAML Tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/).

There's one for Chrome as well.

**Update**

SAML has a number of profiles e.g. SSO.

There isn't really a modern SAML profile for API. The profile they have uses SOAP.

In addition, the SAML token is XML.

API's tend to be REST API using a JWT.

So the token types are different.

This is why there are no SAML tools to call API that I know of.

Comment: This SAML Tracer is used to get saml request and saml response. I want to call my apis and perform operations like post, delete and update. Is there any way to do that? Any tool for this as mentioned above the postman can not do that.